# Selenium webdriver driver.findElement() method return Object - why? What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Code example:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();

driver.get('http://...');
driver.getTitle().then(function(title){
    if("..."===title){
        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('html/body/div/header/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]'))
              .click();
    };
});
driver.wait(function(){
    return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.name('fos_user_registration_form[email]'));
}, 3000, 'Failed to load Registration form');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('fos_user_registration_form[email]'))
      .sendKeys('valentine-test@yandex.ru');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword]'))
      .sendKeys('123Aa');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('btn-submit')).click();//сабмит

driver.wait(function(){ 
    return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.className("form-error-fos-user-registration-form-plainPassword"));
}, 3000, 'Element' + "form-error-fos-user-registration-form-plainPassword" + ' do not found'); 

var flow = webdriver.promise.controlFlow();
function getInputText(){
    errerElement = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className("form-error-fos-user-registration-form-plainPassword"));
};
flow.execute(getInputText).then(function(){
    console.log(errorElement);  //debug printing
    //...
});
```

There are `driver` is `webdriver` class, and his `findElement(locator)` method should returns a `webdriver.WebElement` (as `errorElement`). It should be

```
webdriver.Serializable<{ELEMENT: string}>
    └ webdriver.WebElement
```

In console I get `errorElement` as type `Object`:

```
Object {
  driver_:
   Object {
     session_:
      Object {
        closure_uid_174854009: 13,
        flow_: [Object],
        stack_: [Object],
        parent_: null,
        callbacks_: null,
        state_: 'fulfilled',
        handled_: true,
        value_: [Object],
        queue_: null },
     executor_: { execute: [Function] },
     flow_:
      Object {
        events_: Object {},
        propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
        activeQueue_: [Object],
        taskQueues_: Set {},
        shutdownTask_: null,
        hold_: [Object],
        closure_uid_174854009: undefined },
     fileDetector_: null },
  id_:
   Object {
     closure_uid_174854009: 709,
     flow_:
      Object {
        events_: Object {},
        propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
        activeQueue_: [Object],
        taskQueues_: Set {},
        shutdownTask_: null,
        hold_: [Object],
        closure_uid_174854009: undefined },
     stack_: null,
     parent_: null,
     callbacks_: null,
     state_: 'fulfilled',
     handled_: false,
     value_: Object { ELEMENT: 'unused' },
     queue_:
      Object {
        events_: [Object],
        closure_uid_174854009: 702,
        name_: 'TaskQueue::702',
        flow_: [Object],
        tasks_: [],
        interrupts_: null,
        pending_: null,
        state_: 'finished',
        unhandledRejections_: Set {} } },
  cancel: [Function: bound ],
  isPending: [Function: bound ],
  then: [Function: bound ],
  thenCatch: [Function: bound ],
  thenFinally: [Function: bound ],
  getId: [Function] }
```

This is normal or not?????

Accordingly, I have to work with the methods of the `WebElement` is not as described in the documentation.
Example, in accordance with the documentation`getText()` method should returns `webdriver.promise.Promise<string>` (actually string), but for me is returns a new `Object` ( via `errorText = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className("form-error-fos-user-registration-form-plainPassword")).getText();` then `console.log(errorText)`):

```
Object {
  closure_uid_852736611: 570,
  flow_:
   Object {
     events_: Object {},
     propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
     activeQueue_:
      Object {
        events_: [Object],
        closure_uid_852736611: 624,
        name_: 'TaskQueue::624',
        flow_: [Circular],
        tasks_: [],
        interrupts_: null,
        pending_: null,
        state_: 'new',
        unhandledRejections_: Set {} },
     taskQueues_: Set {},
     shutdownTask_: null,
     hold_:
      { _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 2147483647,
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idleStart: 1136,
        _onTimeout: [Function: wrapper],
        _repeat: [Function] },
     closure_uid_852736611: undefined },
  stack_: null,
  parent_: null,
  callbacks_: null,
  state_: 'fulfilled',
  handled_: false,
  value_: 'Пароль должен состоять из символов латинского алфавита и содержать минимум одну цифру, одну заглавную и одну строчную буквы',
  queue_: null }
```

So as to get the text, I should be doing console.log(errorText.value_).

And so on. For all of elements on site. It's uncomfortable.

### But why???? What I'm doing wrong???

Also there are Properties of element. Error text is within `innerText` properties, so why I can't recieve it by `.getText()` method???

[image]

UPD. Last part of code without controlFlow:

```
function getInputText(){
    return inputText = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className("form-error-fos-user-registration-form-plainPassword")).getText();
};

getInputText().then(function(){
    console.log(inputText); 
});
```

Comment: It returning `Object`, but should returning `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert with promises / control-flow, but I think you're misusing the feature - using things outside their proper scope, and therefore not properly wrapped/unwrapped - and that's causing confusion.

For starters, you have **two** separate `var flow = webdriver.promise.controlFlow();` lines even though what you're (presumably) trying to achieve is to **link** the element finding and the debug printing, which would be one scope at most.

Even then it's unclear why you need `controlFlow()`, as you don't need to schedule tasks, and besides your `getText()` call can just be chained to your `findElement()` call. See the examples [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#control-flows), and as the docs say:

> The WebDriver API is layered on top of the promise manager

---

<s>Can't you simply do...?</s>

<s>console.log( driver.findElement( webdriver.By.className("form-error-fos-user-registration-form-plainPassword")).getText() );</s>

---

**Update:**

Correctly working asynchronous code to log `getText()`:

```
driver.findElement( webdriver.By.className("form-error-fos-user-registration-form-plainPassword") )
      .getText()
      .then(function(txt) {
             console.log("Text is: " + txt);
            });
```

Produces:

```
Text is: Пароль должен состоять из символов латинского алфавита и содержать минимум одну цифру, одну заглавную и одну строчную буквы
```

Basically `getText()` works fine, provided you have a completed `WebElement`. If you don't get the asynchronous dependencies right, your code will run almost immediately the script is loaded, and a Promise will be returned.

Comment: Sorry, two `flow` is my mistake (copy from different part of code) . Acttually, there are one `flow`.
But it is no reason.
I rewrite part of code without controlFlow as;

`function getInputText(){
 return inputText = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('//*[@id="user-bundle-security-modal-content-body"]/div/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/ul/li[1]')).getText();
};
getInputText().then(function(){
    console.log(inputText); `

But I recieve same result.

Comment: You gave an example of the output in the console, but I'm doing the same thing. But I recieve same result: this method returning  `object`, but no `string`.
The essence of my question is that rather than get the inner text as a `string`, I get an `object` from which I must pull out the text through an appeal to the `Value_` property.

Comment: I've just debugged and fixed my `console.log` code. It is still pretty simple, I just forgot that it needed to be an async call too. Hope that helps.

Comment: Indeed, your version of the code is working correctly.
I added in startpost code, which, in my opinion, does the same (correct an asynchronous request). I wrote to him yesterday in the comments, but the lack of formatting possible, making it difficult to understand.
I do not understand what is the difference between my and your code? My code is also made correctly, in my opinion. Can you explain in more details, why my code works differently than yours? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I can't give a 100% authoritative reason why your alternative / updated code fails and returns a Promise not a string, but it must surely be your use of the global `inputText` to store the value of getText() outside of the proper flow/chain. In other words, although `getInputText()` runs at the right time, the *value* has already been obtained (i.e. a Promise) and is not run again. It's just confusion about asynchronous JS, that's all. It's a lot easier if you keep things simple, which is what I tried to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for the Review of my code. it became clearer thanks to you.
Also, I found the reason why my code gave an `object`, not a `string`. I did not give the result further up the chain, because I believe that the return result is **implicitly passed on** through the chain. But it turns out, **it must be passed explicitly** as: `.then(function(inputText){ console.log(inputText);`

I realized that I need to explore in more detail what is the Promise in Javascript. TY.

Comment: I note your answer as a solution.